# How to use mypy to ensure that a NumPy array of floats is passed as function argument?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, mypy

Can mypy check that a NumPy array of floats is passed as a function argument? For the code below mypy is silent when an array of integers or booleans is passed.

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.typing as npt

def half(x: npt.NDArray[np.cfloat]):
    return x/2

print(half(np.full(4,2.1)))
print(half(np.full(4,6)))    # want mypy to complain about this
print(half(np.full(4,True))) # want mypy to complain about this
```

Comment: mypy can't do any better than verifying that a type is an `ndarray` AFAIK. There are however runtimes options using [nptyping](https://pypi.org/project/nptyping/) or [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mypy can check the type of values passed as function arguments, but it currently has limited support for NumPy arrays. You can use the `numpy.typing.NDArray` type hint, as in your code, to specify that the `half` function takes a NumPy array of complex floats as an argument. However, mypy will not raise an error if an array of integers or booleans is passed, as it currently cannot perform type-checking on the elements of the array. To ensure that only arrays of complex floats are passed to the `half` function, you will need to write additional runtime checks within the function to validate the input.